# iPhone Objective-C: Keyboard won't hide with resignFirstResponder, sometimes

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a UITextView which I call resignFirstResponder on when the return key is hit. The text view *does* resign first responder (the flashing cursor thing in the text box goes away), but the keyboard sometimes won't go away.

What could be causing this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: you may need to show some code for us to diagnose further

Comment: All I really have is a method that gets called that calls [userName resignFirstResponder], where userName is a UITextView linked with IB. I know the method gets called because I have a print statement there that prints, and the cursor goes away. Thanks.

Comment: I'm saw this same problem on an app I'm working on. So has BiteSMS: http://forums.bitesms.com/forums/1/topics/3858. I can't reproduce it though. I'm not sure how it happened or how to fix it. Did you ever find out?

Answer (score 1):

Declare the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol

Then implement this

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
 if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
{
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
}

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm.. They have that but left out the `return NO`. Maybe including that will help.