# iPhone: Is it safe to call textViewDidChange?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfielddelegate, uitextviewdelegate

I'm looking at code in a `UIViewController` that conforms to the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol and has an instance variable called `someTextView`.

```
someTextView.text = @"some text";
[self textViewDidChange:someTextView];
```

Is that safe? That doesn't look Kosher to me. Is it even necessary to call `textViewDidChange:`? Won't it get called automatically by `someTextView.text = @"some text"`?

I'm debugging this error [iPhone Objective-C: Keyboard won't hide with resignFirstResponder, sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437360/iphone-objective-c-keyboard-wont-hide-with-resignfirstresponder-sometimes)

Answer (score 7):

read the discussion of [`textViewDidChange:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006897-CH3-SW7)

> Discussion
>
> The text view calls this method in response to user-initiated changes to the text. **This method is not called in response to programmatically initiated changes.**

If it's safe and a good idea to call (UIView-) delegate methods manually depends on the code inside of the method. Sometimes there are valid reasons to do this.

But your bug is most likely not caused by this snippet.