# UITextView: Must I always resignFirstResponder?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield, uitextview, resignfirstresponder

Must I always resignFirstResponder for a `UITextView`? Or, will this happen automatically when its view controller disappears?

I'm asking because I'm having an issue similar to [iPhone Objective-C: Keyboard won't hide with resignFirstResponder, sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437360/iphone-objective-c-keyboard-wont-hide-with-resignfirstresponder-sometimes), where the keyboard stays up even when the nav controller pushes and pops other view controllers. The keyboard works, and when I hit done, it unfocuses the `UITextView` (i.e., the cursor disappears), but the keyboard stays up.

I never found out why this is happening, but maybe it's due to not doing `resignFirstResponder` before pushing another view controller, but I thought it was optional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have to because the [Xcode Sample UICatalog `UITextField`](http://bit.ly/lBnZYB) doesn't call `resignFirstResponder` before the `TextViewController` is popped.

The reason the keyboard got stuck for me is that I was having the same view controller present two view controllers modally at the same time, one after the other. `UIKit` didn't like that.

Answer (score 2):

At a total guess, the UITextView has a reference to the view controller (as its delegate) but does not retain it. When you go to the next screen, the controller is dealloced and then the UITextView (which has perhaps been retained by something else) tries to call back to the dealloced controller and crashes. When you call `resignFirstResponder`, you reverse the order this happens, and therefore no crash.

The way round this to add a `textView.delegate = nil` call in your view controller's `dealloc` method - obviously put it before you release the text view.

Comment: `textView.delegate = nil` is a good suggestion. The view controller (vc) isn't dealloced by pushing another vc because vc's are retained by their navigation controller (nc) until the nc pops the vc from its stack (`nc.viewControllers`). So, I do pop this vc, but the text field is an ivar of the vc, so when I pop the vc, if it's dealloced, then it's text field should be dealloced too because I'm doing that in the vc's dealloc & viewDidUnload. I'm also not sure if this was even causing an issue. It might be something else.

Answer (score 1):

The contract between a UITextView and it's delegate says that the delegate [will send -resignFirstResponder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html) when the text view is done editing. This informs the framework that the view is done editing, fires the events relating to that (willEndEditing and didEndEditing), and allows other parts of the responder hierarchy to react accordingly. Failing to do so might work, but it's not following the contract (that's all a protocol is) it agreed to.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `resignFirstResponder` makes sure that the `text` property contains the actual text shown in the control.

Depending on the state this is not always necessary, but if your controls have resigned first responder, you know that you're working with valid data.

Comment: Now that I checked the documentation you might have a point that this is not necessary for iOS. For NSControl and sub classes (such as NSTextField) on OS X you should call `commitEditing` to make sure any pending edits were committed (or `resignFirstResponder` which caused the same thing to happen), but it might not be required on iOS. It doesn't hurt to do it, though.